# How to get event message using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, event-log

```
$FilterXML = '<QueryList>
                <Query Id="0" Path="System">
                    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name="Service Control Manager"] and (Level=2)]]</Select>
                </Query>
             </QueryList>'
$Errors = Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $FilterXML
$Errors = $Errors | ?{ $_.ToXml().Contains("SomeService") }
```

Problem is that for every object, Message property is null. I can get some info using method .ToXml(), but I can't get message that you could see in windows event viewer under general tab.

If I use Get-EventLog cmdlet, the message property returns string
 about some error.

> The description for Event ID '-1073734793' in Source 'Service Control
>   Manager' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the
>   necessary registry information or mess age DLL files to display the
>   message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following
>   information is part of the event:'SomeService', '2', '0',  '3', 'Run
>   the configured recovery program'

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, which I believe is equivalent to what you were trying.

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable  @{LogName="System";ProviderName="Service Control Manager";Level=2} | ?{$_.message -match "someservice"}
```

I suppose `Get-WinEvent` is able to read those that come as "error message":

I tried two equivalent commands. Got the expected message with `Git-WinEvent` and the "error" message that you got with `Get-EvenLog`:

```
get-eventlog -LogName System | ?{$_.eventid -eq 10016} | select message
```

[image]

```
get-winevent -LogName System  | ?{$_.id -eq 10016} | select message
```

[image]

Comment: Yes we are talking about the same thing. Problem is that for some services this works and for others it doesn't.

Comment: @Primoz - Did you see my updated answer? Seems like you do not have the permission to see some of the messages, as indicated by: `you may not have permission to access them.`

Comment: I'll check as soon as possiblle. Thank you very much for you effort.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the message with WMI?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -Filter "Logfile='system' AND SourceName='Service Control Manager' AND Message LIKE '%SomeService%'" | select Message
```